# C++ freeing memory of nested container and objects

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

There a great chance this question is duplicated, but I wasn't sure how to do a proper search on this. Also it may be trivial to you but it will help me as a beginner a lot!

Say I have three classes, each has a container

```
class A {
    std::map<int, B> container1;
};

class B {
    std::unordered_map<int, C> container2;
};

class C {
    std::vector<int> container3;
};
```

If I have an object 'a' created from class A, with container1/2/3 all filled with data, my questions are the followings:

1. When I call a.container1.clear(), will all the memory allocated for container2 and container3 be freed? If so, how does C++ do this under the hood?
2. When the destructor of 'a' is called, will container2 and 3 be freed?
3. If 1 and 2 are true, do they apply to any nesting combination of containers? For instance here I have map->unordered_map->vector. A different combination could be vector->unordered_map->map.

My gut feeling is that they are all true. Otherwise if I have a very deeply nested structure, it doesn't make sense to go all the way to bottom and explicitly free the memory there.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could provide some documentation that backs up you answer! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer but more of a general comment on how C++ handles those situations: RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization) is the keyword here. Which is a weird way of saying, if an object allocates memory, it is responsable for it. In this case, your containers are all standard and obey the RAII rule. So they will free the memory they allocated. RAII is extremely important. Read up on it thoroughly. It will help you a lot in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: Yes, all nested containers in this scenario will have their memory freed.

The long answer: Let's work from the top.

First, I'm going to assume that these are structs instead of classes (or that the containers have been declared public); otherwise, `a.container1.clear()` won't compile, as container1 would be a private member of a. However, putting that aside:

What happens when you call `a.container1.clear()`? Per https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/clear/, the clear method removes all elements from the container, and those are destroyed.

So, this implies that each object of type B in a.container1 will be destroyed, i.e. B's destructor will be called.

In C++, when an object of a class is destroyed, the destructor of each member of the class is called after that class's destructor has finished (in this case, B's destructor is the default compiler-generated destructor, as no user-supplied destructor is present). So, after B is destroyed, the destructor of B.container2 will be called. Since container2 is an unordered_map, its destructor will destroy all of its contained elements ([https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/~unordered_map/](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/%7Eunordered_map/))

Since container2's elements are of type C, each element of type C in container2 will have its destructor called. Again, container3's destructor will be called. And, as a vector, container3's storage capacity will be deallocated, i.e. freed ([https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/~vector/](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/%7Evector/)).

Now, we've worked our way to the bottom, and we've seen that all memory is freed!

Comment: `B`s destructor does not call the destructor of `container2`.   The process of destroying a `B` calls `B`s destructor *then* destroys all its members in reverse of their order of initialisation (and the order of initialisation is the order of their declaration).  The description becomes then recursive - destroying each member calls its destructor, then - if that member has members - destroys each of its members (again, in reverse order of their initialisation).

Comment: True; I'll edit appropriately.

Comment: @Marion If a struct has its members as objects and other containers, will the destructor of each subobject and subcontainer get called?

Comment: Yes, see above in my response: "In C++, when an object of a class is destroyed, the destructor of each member of the class is called after that class's destructor has finished"